# How to restrict 'date' type inputs in a page based on the previous input?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, date

I am using a very normal html form with input type = "date' to collect two dates. Now, To restrict the end date, from going beyond the begin date (Ex : If the begin date is 06-05-2013 (dd-mm-yyyy), the end date should not be able to take values before that day.) How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jquery should fix your problem: http://2008.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerStartEnd.html

After you select the start of first data in the first picker, the end data or the second data picker starts after the data that was picked in the first date picker.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place javascript validation to achieve this. Bind a function with blur event, that will do the validation and if validation is a failure you do the appropriate error handling.

In order to how to use blur event, please refer to

"http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp"